# Flutter FutureBuilder in SliverList

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-sliver

I want to list items from a FutureBuilder inside a SliverList. I found a possible solution here [How to use FutureBuilder inside SliverList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146850/how-to-use-futurebuilder-inside-sliverlist) but not worked for me.

This is my code, it works, but i cannot declare the "childCount" as "snapshot.data.lenght" because of it is outside the FutureBuilder

```
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return FutureBuilder(
              future: getList1(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        snapshot.data?[index]['docName'],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
          childCount: 2,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Is there any better way or best practice to list FutureBluider in a SliverList?

Comment: Does it work properly when wrapping CustomScrollView with FutureBuilder?

Comment: Yes, the wrapping works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FutureBuilder on top of SliverList and make sure to return sliver widget from futureBuilder on everystate.

```dart
class _detailState extends State<detail> {
  late final future = getList1();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
        FutureBuilder<List?>(
          future: future,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                      "${snapshot.data?[index]['docName']}",
                    )),
                  );
                },
                childCount: snapshot.data?.length,
              ));
            } else {
              return const SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked. It seems a very good way to solve it.